# Combine PDF files into 3 PDF files

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that combines the PDF files in a folder into one PDF folder

```
Sub PDFs_Combine_LateBound()
Dim PdfDst As Object, PdfSrc As Object
Dim sPdfComb As String, sPdf As String
Dim b As Byte

    Rem Set Combined Pdf filename - save the combined pdf in a new file in order to preserve original pdfs
    sPdfComb = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Pdf Combined" & Format(Now, " mmdd_hhmm ") & ".pdf"   'change as required

    Rem Open Destination Pdf
    b = 1
    sPdf = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "firstpdf" & b & ".pdf"
    Set PdfDst = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    If Not (PdfDst.Open(sPdf)) Then
        MsgBox "Error opening destination pdf:" & vbCrLf _
            & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdf & "]" & vbCrLf _
            & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do

        Rem Set & Validate Source filename
        b = b + 1
        sPdf = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "firstpdf" & b & ".pdf"
        If Dir(sPdf, vbArchive) = vbNullString Then Exit Do

        Rem Open Source filename
        Set PdfSrc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        If Not (PdfSrc.Open(sPdf)) Then
            MsgBox "Error opening source pdf:" & vbCrLf _
                & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdf & "]" & vbCrLf _
                & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
            GoTo Exit_Sub
        End If

        With PdfDst

            Rem Insert Source filename pages
            If Not (.InsertPages(-1 + .GetNumPages, PdfSrc, 0, PdfSrc.GetNumPages, 0)) Then
                MsgBox "Error inserting source pdf:" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdf & "]" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
                GoTo Exit_Sub
            End If

            Rem Save Combined Pdf
            If Not (.Save(1, sPdfComb)) Then
                MsgBox "Error saving combined pdf:" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdfComb & "]" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
                GoTo Exit_Sub
            End If

            PdfSrc.Close
            Set PdfSrc = Nothing

        End With

'        sPdf = Dir(sPdf, vbArchive)
'    Loop While sPdf <> vbNullString
    Loop

    MsgBox "Pdf files combined successfully!", vbExclamation

Exit_Sub:
    PdfDst.Close

   End Sub
```

The code is working fine as for combining the PDF files

But what I need is a bit different
Say I have 5 PDF files with 3 pages at each pdf .. and I need to combine the first page from all the files and this is the first output PDF
Then take the second page for all the files and combine to be the second output PDF.
Then take the third page for all the files and combine to be the third output PDF.

So the final output would be three PDF files ..

Comment: Change the Do While to a For Loop with a nested For Loop and then combine the pages in the layered order.

Comment: Can you help me by posting an answer as I couldn't apply that?